# Django - Changed url to re_path, now getting 404 error

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I've changed my url to re_path and am now getting 404, not found error. Any ideas? Here is my code for the urls.py and html which includes the ajax:

```
re_path(r'^get_mmm_ingredients/(?P<ingredient_type>\w+)/$', get_mmm_ingredients),

<script>
    // populate ingredients
    let ingredient;
    $("select[name='ingredient_type']").change(function() {
        const ingredient_type = $(this).val();
        const data = {"item": ingredient_type};
        ingredient = $("select[name='ingredient']");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/get_mmm_ingredients/' + ingredient_type + '/',
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                // empty value dropdown and add options
                ingredient.empty();
                ingredient.append('<option>Select</option>');
                $.each(data, function (index, text) {
                    ingredient.append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(index).html(text)
                    );
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved by changing my main urls.py to:

```
re_path(r'^', include('xxxxxxxxxx.urls')),
```